# handle Back and menu button in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm new in phone gap. I'm working on phone gap app for android.
In this i want to fire an event on menu and back button of the device.
I've try  a lot but can't understand how to do this.
Please help me..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hello, can you please post the code that you have tried so we can see if there is anything wrong with the code? See this article on how to handle the back button and other buttons http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add event listener in ready function for menu and back button. Below is the code.. It works for me.. for more detail please go to Phonegap Site.. here is the link of phonegap platform api guide. [Click here.](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_index.md.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

       document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
    });

    function onBackKeyDown() {
        // your code..
        alert('Back Button pressed..');
    }
    function onMenuKeyDown() {
        // your code..
        alert('Menu Button pressed..');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To attach a function to the backbutton you can do it this way:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

To attach it to the menu button would be this:

```
document.addEventListener("menubutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

Just make sure the device is ready before adding this functions:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", yourBackButtonCallbackFunction, false);
    document.addEventListener("menubutton", yourMenuButtonCallbackFunction, false);
}
```

Comment: How to make use of `backbutton` in **InAppBrowser**?